# Make tag as variable for using in if::else in Django Template

Tags: python, regex, django

I have a Django template tag, that match in current url regexp (i want use it for create prints in template if regexp match regexp, in this case, i use it for create "active" element in site menu).

```
# project/templatetags/tags.py 
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def match_url(context, match):
    request = context.get('request')

    if not request:
        raise Exception

    return re.match(match, request.get_full_path())
```

And i want use it like this

```
{% load tags %}

{% if match_url "^/about" %}
    <h1>About page</h1>
{% endif %}

{% if somevar == "asfd" || match_url "^/cat/1" %}
    :param: somevar: variable that I passed from view
{% endif %}
```

I know about `{% with blabla as somethink %}` and `{% match_url blabla as somethink  %}`. I need it as I have shown above, because it is more convenient in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Make a `{% if_match_url "^/about" %}...{% endif %}` template tag that does what you want.

The template language is intentionally limited, to make sure you don't put too much magic in your templates. People will tell you to do this stuff in view instead of template.